# Paragraph does not pagebreak after a code chunk when using noweb

Tags: page-breaking, literate-programming

I am using literate programming (more specifically noweb) for writing a tech report. But something seems to prevent paragraphs from breaking at the end of a page directly after code segments, which leads to large empty spaces at the end of some pages.

> MWE.nw

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{noweb}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

<<first code chunk>>=
My Code
@ %

%\lipsum[1-5] % This works
\lipsum[1-6] % This doesn't

\end{document}
```

When compiling this to a tex-file using

> noweave -delay MWE.nw > MWE.tex

I get the following file

> MWE.tex

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}% ===> this file was generated automatically by noweave --- better not edit it

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{noweb}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\nwfilename{MWE.nw}\nwbegincode{1}\moddef{first code chunk}\endmoddef\nwstartdeflinemarkup\nwenddeflinemarkup
My Code
\nwendcode{}\nwbegindocs{2}%

%\lipsum[1-5] % This works
\lipsum[1-6] % This doesn't

\end{document}
\nwenddocs{}
```

If the lipsum fits completely onto the first page it gets sorted there, otherwise it starts on a new page.

Does someone have any idea what may cause this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found something. I would like to share the solution that worked for me.

In `noweb.sty` the command `\nwendcode` is defined with a `\filbreak` at its end, which is causing the problem.

```
\def\nwendcode{\endtrivlist \endgroup \filbreak}
```

So a first solution is to just redefine the command and deleting the `\filbreak`

```
\def\nwendcode{\endtrivlist \endgroup}
```

But now there is nothing that prevents the code segments from splitting on two pages all the time. So I redefined `\nwbegincode` as well to add a samepage environment.

```
\let\oldnwbc\nwbegincode
\def\nwbegincode{\begin{samepage}\oldnwbc}
\def\nwendcode{\endtrivlist \endgroup\end{samepage}}
```

I think this has some effect, but unfortunately the name of the code chunks still gets separated from the code itself, which leads to many pagebreaks in between the names and the code. Finally I found the neat little package `needspace`, which allows me to reserve some space for the following lines. With this, page breaking finally works as expected.

```
\usepackage{needspace}

\let\oldnwbc\nwbegincode
\def\nwbegincode{\needspace{5\baselineskip}\oldnwbc}
\def\nwendcode{\endtrivlist \endgroup}
```